# Accessing enum values of another object in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

Im trying to assign an enum value of one object to another object in the same json schema. I need the value of object2 in object1 after the user has selected the option. Is it possible?

```
{ schema:{
  "object1":{},
  "object2:{
        "type":"string",
        "enum":["option1","option2"]}
```

Comment: Have a look at `if` `then` `else` https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.6 - If after that you still need help, let me know (or someone else might be able to pick up this question)

Comment: Thank you @Relequestual. But could you please provide me a sample code for the scenario mentioned above. I am trying to run the schema here - "http://ulion.github.io/jsonform/playground/bootstrap3/?data=#". But irrespective of what I do, I am unable to get output. I think my syntax is wrong, and I'm pretty new to json, so the whole thing has been very confusing.

Comment: Ah, OK. That changes things. JSON Schema isn't designed for forms. Some people want to use it to make forms, and have created their own way to do this. I hadn't picked up on when you said "user has selected" that you meant using a form. You may find https://surveyjs.io/Library will provide you with functionality you require.

Comment: Wow! Its an amazing site! Thanks a lot @Relequestual :)